powershell 5.1, remove a file of subsequent Update-FormatData
if I add format data to my current session via a temporary .format.ps1xml file and then delete the temporary file, every subsequent call to Update-FormatData will complain about a missing file.
are the only ways of stopping these complaints to restart powershell or use an ugly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue, or is there a way to make powershell forget the files used for testing?
edit
at first I run a script which creates a .format.ps1xml file on the fly for a custom PSType, adds format data using
Update-FormatData -AppendPath C:\Temp\f9c23d07-7711-4846-9c68-65ec861bc91d.Format.ps1xml

then deletes the no-longer-needed .format.ps1xml temp file, and finally produces result using the custom PSType.
from that moment on, if I use Update-FormatData I get this error message
[PS] C:\> Update-FormatData
Update-FormatData : Could not find file 'C:\Temp\f9c23d07-7711-4846-9c68-65ec861bc91d.Format.ps1xml'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-FormatData
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-FormatData], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateFormatDataCommand

I would like a way to make PowerShell forget the temporary .format.ps1xml file.

Please post the relevant error message(s) in full

@MathiasR.Jessen I added more info

Try -PrependPath : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-formatdata?view=powershell-7.4#-prependpath

@jdweng as expected, I get the very same error on subsequent calls of Update-FormatData when I add the temp file using -PrependPath

Update-FormatData only needs to run if you modify an existing ps1xml file and need to reload the file.  Why do you need to use Update-FormatData?

@jdweng because I have multiple scripts, each one defining on the fly its own format data for its own custom PSType result calling Update-FormatData. if I run only one of the scripts within a PS session, all is OK, if I run more than one, I get the error.

It doesn't matter if you have one or more than one format file.  You only need to use Update-FormatData if the format file changes.  You are not changing any format file.  You are just using more than one format file and do not need to use Update-FormatData.

It's easier to create a module, no Update-FormatData needed
